# Spring Statemachine reset state not trigger entry action

Tags: spring-statemachine

configure code

`states
                .withStates()
                    .initial(OrderState.Create)
                    .state(OrderState.Create, startAction)
                    .state(OrderState.Payed, paymentAction)
                    .states(EnumSet.allOf(OrderState.class));`

run code

`stateMachine
                .getStateMachineAccessor()
                .doWithAllRegions(access -> {
                    access.resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>    (OrderState.Payed, null, null, null, null));
                });
    stateMachine.start();`

paymentAction not trigger when start,
how to trigger

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code never enters state `Payed` which would run `paymentAction`. It only goes to initial state `Create`. Thought you didn't show any transition configs so only way it would enter that state if there is an anonymous transition between `Create` and `Payed`.

Comment: I have a similar setup with 3 states and 2 transitions. Like shown above, I want to start the statemachine in a state that is not the initial state (here Payed). But the statemachine still starts with the initial state. Is it possible to start the machine with a specific state that in my case would come from the database?